# how to find a word that contain "a" and also end with "d"? (Bash Regex)

Tags: regex, grep

```
  grep -E "a|d$$" filename
```

This is what I have but it does not works.
Can I get some advice how I should approach it?

Comment: can you given an example input and desired output? do you want each word, each line that contains any such word, ...?

Comment: Not a very nice way : `grep -E "*a*.*d$"` filename

Comment: Is the file one word per line, or do you have to match words anywhere in the line?

Comment: @Riz a repetition metachar like `*` at the start of a regexp is undefined behavior and is always wrong as whatever you want it to mean there is a correct, unambiguous way to write that.

Comment: [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you as right now there's several different interpretations of your question that you can clear up with sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is OR, not AND. So your command returns lines that either contain `a` or end with `d` (I assume `$$` was a typo for `$`). To match both conditions sequentially, just put one pattern after the other, don't use `|`.

If the file is one word per line, use:

```
grep 'a.*d$' filename
```

If there are multiple words per line, and you're using GNU `grep`, you can use:

```
grep -P 'a\w*d\b' filename
```

`\w` matches word characters, and `\b` matches a word boundary after the `d`.

This will match the whole line containing the word. If you only want to return the word itself, use

```
grep -P -o '\b\w*a\w*d\b' filename
```

The `-o` option means to only show the part of the line that matches the regexp

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk '{for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i~/a.*d$/) {print $i}}}'
```

Using GNU awk, or any awk that implements regex for the record separator (`RS`):

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '/a.*d$/'
```

Using GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '[^[:space:]]*a[^[:space:]]*d(?=[[:space:]]|$)'
```